# How to make codable class to decode json array which doesn't have a key/name?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying to decode following JSON to my codable object.

```
[
        {
            "Action": "CREDIT",
            "Status": 1,
            "TransactionDate": "2019-09-20T04:23:19.530137Z",
            "Description": "test"
        },
        {
            "Action": "CREDIT",
            "Status": 1,
            "TransactionDate": "2019-09-20T04:23:19.530137Z",
            "Description": "test"
        },
        {
            "Action": "CREDIT",
            "Status": 1,
            "TransactionDate": "2019-09-20T04:23:19.530137Z",
            "Description": "test"
        }
]
```

My codable classes be like..

```
struct UserWalletHistoryList: Codable {
    var historyList: [UserWalletHistory]
}


struct UserWalletHistory: Codable{
    var Action: String?
    var Status: Int?
    var TransactionDate: String?
    var Description: String?
}
```

but it is not successful. I think it's because of the variable name **historyList** since there is no such key as `historyList` in the JSON. Then..., what's it supposed to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete `UserWalletHistoryList`

```
struct UserWalletHistoryList: Codable {
   var historyList: [UserWalletHistory]
}
```

and decode an array of `UserWalletHistory`

```
JSONDecoder().decode([UserWalletHistory].self, from: data)
```

and as the JSON provides all keys in all dictionaries declare the struct members as non-optional and add CodingKeys to map the uppercase keys to lowercase member names

```
struct UserWalletHistory : Codable {
    let action: String
    let status: Int
    let transactionDate: String
    let description: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { 
        case action = "Action"
        case status = "Status"
        case transactionDate = "TransactionDate"
        case description = "Description" 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know that!  I guess you could just use a typedef for the `[ ]` to keep it similar.

Comment: It works @vadian. And the CodingKeys stuff is really useful.